# Is there any way to clone a specific brach in git desktop?

Tags: github, github-desktop

I tried but its cloning whole repository. I wanted to clone only specific branch in that repository

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14930421/6309

Comment: The OP is asking about GiHub Desktop, not Git, in general.

Answer (score -2):

You only can clone a whole repository except a branch, the code is:

```
git clone -b mybranch --single-branch git://sub.domain.com/repo.git
```

If you already have the repository cloned, you can refresh the branch you want, if you have forked the project you can refresh the specific branch you want. the code is:

```
git checkout 'branch if you want to change to refresh it'
git pull <URL of REPOSITORY> 'branch that you want to refresh it'
git commit -m "message"
git push upstream 'branch that you want to refresh it'
```