# How to use Git for graphics and sound-intensive iOS development?

Tags: ios, xcode, git

As an example, I have a game that consists of some 800 images and about 400 sound clips.  How would you approach using Git with such a project?

In doing some research I found threads on SO stating that Perforce has 100% of the gaming world because it is well-designed to deal with media.  If that is the case, how so?

I came across this but have not tried it yet: https://github.com/schacon/git-media

I'd appreciate hearing from anyone who has.

Here's the write-up where I learned of git-media:  http://massivelyfun.com/git-for-game-development/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See   [Managing Large Binary Files with Git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/540535/1286639).  There are options like using a *submodule* or '*git annex*'

Comment: Lots of interesting ideas there.  Thanks.