# How to manage a project with huge resource size on Git or any source control

Tags: git, version-control

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Managing large binary files with git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540535/managing-large-binary-files-with-git)

The situation is that I have a game or any project that attached to huge resource such as model files, images, and sound files. I develop the project using Git, and as far as I know and concern what's on Git or any source control should be only source code not huge resource. So my question is that how developers manage to resolve the burden and effort to match the right resource to the version of code checkout from Git itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should certainly put your resource files under version control, too.

Since you are using git you might want to use a separate repository for the big stuff and include it as a [submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) in your main repository.

This has the advantage that you still have proper version control of everything while being able to clone the main repository without cloning the resources.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion on using submodule in git, it's really worth knowing and worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have two choices. Either put the resources in the git, or keep them separate. Both have advantages and disadvantages:

Advantages of **keeping them in git**:

- You can rollback changes in model files
- You can modify the resources according to the main source if anything in your file formats or directory structure changes (this is not so easy when using submodules)

Disadvantages:

- Artists may need to know git
- Binary content blows up your repository in size