# Binary Storage using Git and nuGet

Tags: git, version-control, nuget, binaryfiles

My company is moving to git. Currently, when dealing with binary files, we check them into our current source control system. We want to get to a CI environment, but seeing as how our codebase is very large and spread out, we want to take baby steps. We would like to be able to store the binary files in a separate repository so we can keep history and not clutter our code repositories. From there, we are thinking about using nuGet (we are .net) as a dependency management solution for our projects. Does this approach make sense? Has anyone else tried something similar? I'm looking for thoughts and opinions on this. Any advice would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Git isn't the best at handling *large* binary files.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540535/managing-large-binary-files-with-git) for some of the reasons why.  But, if you do store binary files in git, make sure that git knows they are binary.  The best way to do this is with a [`.gitattributes` file](http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-2.html#Binary-Files), where you can specify patterns of filenames that should be treated as binary.  This tells git the file can't be diffed, merged, etc. like a regular text file can.