# How git branches and tags are stored in disks?

Tags: git, tags, branch, git-branch

I recently checked one of my git repositories at work, which had more than 10,000 branches and more than 30000 tags. The total size of the repo, after a fresh clone is 12Gigs. I am sure there is no reason to have 10000 branches. So I believe they would occupy considerable amount of space in the disks. So, my questions are as follows

1. How branches and tags are stored in disks, like what data-structure used, what information is stored for every branch?
2. How do I get the metadata about the branches? like when that branch was created, what the size of the branch is.

Comment: Git branches are effectively just pointers to commits.

Comment: So that's an SHA per branch or tag, in files in `.git/refs`, all of them (except `HEAD`), 41 bytes = SHA (40 bytes) + NEWLINE (1 byte)

Comment: Yes, except that typical file systems allocate some minimum block size (like 512 bytes or 4k or whatever).  Also, the names themselves use up space in the directories.  Hence, ref packing.

Comment: Note: pack-refs should be much faster to create with Git 2.2+ (November 2014): See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26962083/6309)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All git references (branches, tags, notes, stashes, etc) use the same system.  These are:

- the references themselves, and
- "reflogs"

Reflogs are stored in `.git/logs/refs/` based on the reference-name, with one exception: reflogs for `HEAD` are stored in `.git/logs/HEAD` rather than `.git/logs/refs/HEAD`.

References come either "loose" or "packed".  Packed refs are in `.git/packed-refs`, which is a flat file of (SHA-1, refname) pairs for simple refs, plus extra information for annotated tags.  "Loose" refs are in `.git/refs/name`.  These files contain either a raw SHA-1 (probably the most common), or the literal string `ref:` followed by the name of another reference for symbolic refs (usually only for `HEAD` but you can make others).  Symbolic refs are not packed (or at least, I can't seem to make that happen :-) ).

Packing tags and "idle" branch heads (those that are not being updated actively) saves space and time.  You can use [`git pack-refs`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pack-refs.html) to do this.  However, `git gc` invokes `git pack-refs` for you, so generally you don't need to do this yourself.

Answer (score 24):

So, I’m going to expand on the topic a bit and explain *how* Git stores *what*. Doing so will explain what information is stored, and what exactly matters for the size of the repository. As a fair warning: this answer is rather long :)

### Git objects

Git is essentially a database of objects. Those objects come in four different types and are all identified by a SHA1 hash of their contents. The four types are *blobs*, *trees*, *commits* and *tags*.

#### Blob

A *blob* is the simplest type of objects. It stores the *content* of a file. So for each file content you store within your Git repository, a single blob object exists in the object database. As it stores only the file *content*, and not metadata like file names, this is also the mechanism that prevents files with identical content from being stored multiple times.

#### Tree

Going one level up, the *tree* is the object that puts the blobs into a directory structure. A single tree corresponds to a single directory. It is essentially a list of files and subdirectories, with each entry containing a file mode, a file or directory name, and a reference to the Git object that belongs to the entry. For subdirectories, this reference points to the tree object that describes the subdirectory; for files, this reference points to the blob object storing the file contents.

#### Commit

Blobs and trees are already enough to represent a complete file system. To add the versioning on top of that, we have *commit* objects. Commit objects are created whenever you commit something in Git. Each commit represents a snapshot in the history of revisions.

It contains a reference to the tree object describing the root directory of the repository. This also means that every commit that actually introduces some changes at least requires a new tree object (likely more).

A commit also contains a reference to its parent commits. While there is usually just a single parent (for a linear history), a commit can have any number of parents in which case it’s usually called a *merge commit*. Most workflows will only ever make you do merges with two parents, but you can really have any other number too.

And finally, a commit also contains the meta data you expect a commit to have: Author and committer (name and time) and of course the commit message.

That is all that is necessary to have a full version control system; but of course there is one more object type:

#### Tag

Tag objects are one way to store tags. To be precise, tag objects store *annotated tags*, that are tags that have—similar to commits—some meta information. They are created by `git tag -a` (or when creating a signed tag) and require a tag message. They also contain a reference to the commit object they are pointing at, and a tagger (name and time).

### References

Up until now, we have a full versioning system, with annotated tags, but all our objects are identified by their SHA1 hash. That’s of course a bit annoying to use, so we have some other thing to make it easier: References.

References come in different flavors, but the most important thing about them is this: They are simple text files containing 40 characters—the SHA1 hash of the object they are pointing to. Because they are this simple, they are *very* cheap, so working with many references is no problem at all. It creates no overhead and there is no reason not to use them.

There are usually three “types” of references: Branches, tags and remote branches. They really work the same and all point to commit objects; except for *annotated* tags which point to tag objects (normal tags are just commit references though too). The difference between them is how you create them, and in which subpath of `/refs/` they are stored. I won’t cover this now though, as this is explained in nearly every Git tutorial; just remember: References, i.e. branches, are extremely cheap, so don’t hesitate to create them for just about everything.

### Compression

Now because torek mentioned something about Git’s compression in his answer, I want to clarify this a bit. Unfortunately he mixed a few things up.

So, usually for new repositories, all Git objects are stored in `.git/objects` as files identified by their SHA1 hash. The first two characters are stripped from the filename and are used to partition the files into multiple folders, just so it gets a bit easier to navigate.

At some point, when the history gets bigger or when it is triggered by something else, Git will start to compress objects. It does this by packing multiple objects into a single *pack file*. How this exactly works is not really that important; it will reduce the amount of individual Git objects and efficiently store them in single, indexed archives (at this point, Git will use delta compression btw.). The pack files are then stored in `.git/objects/pack` and can easily get a few hundred MiB in size.

For references, the situation is somewhat similar, although a lot simpler. All *current* references are stored in `.git/refs`, e.g. branches in `.git/refs/heads`, tags in `.git/refs/tags` and remote branches in `.git/refs/remotes/<remote>`. As mentioned above, they are simple text files containing only the 40 character identifier of the object they are pointing at.

At some point, Git will move older references—of any type—into a single lookup file: `.git/packed-refs`. That file is just a long list of hashes and reference names, one entry per line. References that are kept in there are removed from the `refs` directory.

### Reflogs

Torek mentioned those as well, *reflogs* are essentially just logs for references. They keep track of what happens to references. If you do anything that affects a reference (commit, checkout, reset, etc.) then a new log entry is added simply to log what happened. It also provides a way to go back after you did something wrong. A common use case for example is to access the reflog after accidentally resetting a branch to somewhere it wasn’t supposed to go. You can then use `git reflog` to look at the log and see where the reference was pointing at before. As loose Git objects are not immediately deleted (objects that are part of the history are never deleted), you can usually restore the previous situation easily.

Reflogs are however *local*: They only keep track of what happens to your local repository. They are not shared with remotes, and are never transferred. A freshly cloned repository will have a reflog with a single entry, it being the clone action. They are also limited to a certain length after which older actions are pruned, so they won’t become a storage problem.

### Some final words

So, getting back to your actual question. When you clone a repository, Git will usually already receive the repository in a packed format. This is already done to save transfer time. References are very cheap, so they are never the cause of big repositories. However, because of Git’s nature, a single current commit object has a whole acyclic graph in it that eventually will reach the very first commit, the very first tree, and the very first blob. So a repository will always contain all the information for all revisions. That is what makes repositories with a long history big. Unfortunately, there is not really much you can do about it. Well, you could cut off older history at some part but that will leave you with a broken repository (you do this by cloning with the `--depth` parameter).

And as for your second question, as I explained above, branches are just references to commits, and references are only pointers to Git objects. So no, there is not really any metadata about branches you can get from them. The only thing that might give you an idea is the first commit you made when branching off in your history. But having branches does not automatically mean that there is actually a branch kept in the history (fast-foward merging and rebasing works against it), and just because there is some branching-off in the history that does not mean that the branch (the reference, the pointer) still exists.

Comment: I just came across this answer while looking for an existing stackoverflow discussion about git objects and object compression, and I want to add a note: I deliberately skipped over object compression entirely as the original question was *only* about references.  The `pack-refs` code only does reference packing; object packing is done with `git pack-objects`.  (I probably should have mentioned reflog expiration though.)

Comment: Make that, both `pack-object` and `repack`.

Answer (score 2):

You have:

- `packed-refs`,
- **`reftable`**. (see the last section of this answer)

Regarding **`pack-refs`**, the process of creating them should be much faster with Git 2.2+ (November 2014)

See [commit 9540ce5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9540ce5030853ffbb7e11c30aa59a5e45095d32c) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff):

### refs: write `packed_refs` file using stdio

> We write each line of a new packed-refs file individually using a `write()` syscall (and sometimes 2, if the ref is peeled). Since each line is only about 50-100 bytes long, this creates a lot of system call overhead.
>
> We can instead open a `stdio` handle around our descriptor and use `fprintf` to write to it. The extra buffering is not a problem for us, because nobody will read our new packed-refs file until we call `commit_lock_file` (by which point we have flushed everything).
>
> **On a pathological repository with 8.5 million refs, this dropped the time to run `git pack-refs` from 20s to 6s**.

---

Update Sept 2016: Git 2.11+ will include chained tags inpack-refs ("[chained tags and `git clone --single-branch --branch tag`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39527106/6309)")

And the same Git 2.11 will now use *fully* **pack bitmap**.

See [commit 645c432](https://github.com/git/git/commit/645c432d6196903bcd9e8a82d150aac1428ccf34), [commit 702d1b9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/702d1b95831c1a34a217ad63b14895226962955a) (10 Sep 2016) by [Kirill Smelkov (`navytux`)](https://github.com/navytux).
Helped-by: [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 7f109ef](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7f109ef54e96ac7ae7e036487b881432170a3817), 21 Sep 2016)</sup>

> ### `pack-objects`: use reachability bitmap index when generating non-stdout pack

**Pack bitmaps** were introduced in Git 2.0 ([commit 6b8fda2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6b8fda2db1d69606954711b606c546c0e4e51680), Dec. 2013), from [google's work for JGit](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Using-bitmaps-to-accelerate-fetch-and-clone-td7567982.html).

> We use the bitmap API to perform the `Counting Objects`
> phase in pack-objects, rather than a traditional walk through the object
> graph.

Now (2016):

> Starting from [6b8fda2 (pack-objects: use bitmaps when packing objects)](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6b8fda2db1d69606954711b606c546c0e4e51680), if a repository has bitmap index, pack-objects can nicely speedup "Counting objects" graph traversal phase.
> **That however was done only for case when resultant pack is sent to stdout, not written into a file**.
>
> One might want to generate on-disk packfiles for a specialized object transfer.
> It would be useful to have some way of overriding this heuristic:
> to tell pack-objects that even though it should generate on-disk files, it is still OK to use the reachability bitmaps to do the traversal.

---

Note: GIt 2.12 illlustrates that using  bitmap has a side-effect on `git gc --auto`

See [commit 1c409a7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1c409a705cb30ae3db6cdd48757c4a85f51456d4), [commit bdf56de](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bdf56de896b48d6fe3ad90e92138b5fd6579748d) (28 Dec 2016) by [David Turner (`csusbdt`)](https://github.com/csusbdt).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit cf417e2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cf417e2c1f50578d8f7eccb65b981042d05939f0), 18 Jan 2017)</sup>

> The bitmap index only works for single packs, so requesting an
> incremental repack with bitmap indexes makes no sense.
>
> Incremental repacks are incompatible with bitmap indexes

---

Git 2.14 refines `pack-objects`

See [commit da5a1f8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/da5a1f81008f89f4e533006df8fa536e43c9c677), [commit 9df4a60](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9df4a6074a98740b70b980d43dca5203db0ff688) (09 May 2017) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 137a261](https://github.com/git/git/commit/137a2613a07e556fd77fe374c6f4edd2d5e1b1fc), 29 May 2017)</sup>

> ### `pack-objects`: disable pack reuse for object-selection options

> If certain options like `--honor-pack-keep`, `--local`, or `--incremental` are used with pack-objects, then we need to feed each potential object to `want_object_in_pack()` to see if it should be filtered out.
> But when the bitmap reuse_packfile optimization is in effect, we do not call
> that function at all, and in fact skip adding the objects to the `to_pack` list entirely.
>
> This means we have a bug: for certain requests we will silently ignore those options and include objects in that pack that should not be there.
>
> The problem has been present since the inception of the pack-reuse code in [6b8fda2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6b8fda2db1d69606954711b606c546c0e4e51680) (pack-objects: use bitmaps when packing objects, 2013-12-21), but it was unlikely to come up in practice.
> These options are generally used for on-disk packing, not transfer packs (which go to `stdout`), but we've never allowed pack reuse for non-stdout packs (until
> [645c432](https://github.com/git/git/commit/645c432d6196903bcd9e8a82d150aac1428ccf34), we did not even use bitmaps, which the reuse optimization relies on; after that, we explicitly turned it off when not packing to `stdout`).

---

With Git 2.27 (Q2 2020), the tests around non-bitmap packs is refined.

See [commit 14d2778](https://github.com/git/git/commit/14d277879cfe4ef2f2d58f9a30458d2d84cee1df) (26 Mar 2020) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 2205461](https://github.com/git/git/commit/220546156ab3d9c2259e5156b938ef7a823a28a3), 22 Apr 2020)</sup>

> ### [`p5310`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/14d277879cfe4ef2f2d58f9a30458d2d84cee1df): stop timing non-bitmap pack-to-disk
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> Commit [645c432d61](https://github.com/git/git/commit/645c432d6196903bcd9e8a82d150aac1428ccf34) ("`pack-objects`: use reachability bitmap index when generating non-stdout pack", 2016-09-10, Git v2.11.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7f109ef54e96ac7ae7e036487b881432170a3817) listed in [batch #4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6fe1b1407ed91823daa5d487abe457ff37463349)) added two timing tests for packing to an on-disk file, both with and without bitmaps.
>
> However, the non-bitmap one isn't interesting to have as part of p5310's regression suite. It *could* be used as a baseline to show off the improvement in the bitmap case, but:
>
> - the point of the `t/perf` suite is to find performance regressions, and it won't help with that.
>   We don't compare the numbers between two tests (which the perf suite has no idea are even related), and any change in its numbers would have nothing to do with bitmaps.
>
> it did show off the improvement in the commit message of [645c432d61](https://github.com/git/git/commit/645c432d6196903bcd9e8a82d150aac1428ccf34), but it wasn't even necessary there.
> The bitmap case already shows an improvement (because before the patch, it behaved the same as the non-bitmap case), and the perf suite is even able to show the difference between the before and after measurements.
>
> On top of that, it's one of the most expensive tests in the suite, clocking in around 60s for `linux.git` on my machine (as compared to 16s for the bitmapped version). And by default when using "`./run`", we'd run it three times!
>
> So let's just drop it. It's not useful and is adding minutes to perf runs.

---

### Reftables

With Git 2.28 (Q3 2020), Preliminary clean-ups around refs API, plus file format specification documentation for the reftable backend.

See [commit ee9681d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ee9681d94960e075f310ce8276539aa3169fd152), [commit 10f007c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/10f007c37031df64a5786f032f52fd1327920e0d), [commit 84ee4ca](https://github.com/git/git/commit/84ee4ca10d7f598542eb2c1ea2cdf6199f9bdee1), [commit cdb73ca](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cdb73ca56f21835b93345442a96c97f6a0589ef7), [commit d1eb22d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d1eb22da09e0ffebbd6c16ef1d0e952ec7b88b8d) (20 May 2020) by [Han-Wen Nienhuys (`hanwen`)](https://github.com/hanwen).
See [commit 35e6c47](https://github.com/git/git/commit/35e6c47404852e9c529d55a3bd374305fb08b743) (20 May 2020) by [Jonathan Nieder (`artagnon`)](https://github.com/artagnon).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit eebb51b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eebb51ba8cab97c0b3f3f18eaab7796803b8494b), 12 Jun 2020)</sup>

> ### [`reftable`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/35e6c47404852e9c529d55a3bd374305fb08b743): file format documentation
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jonathan Nieder</sup>

> Shawn Pearce explains:
>
> Some repositories contain a lot of references (e.g. android at 866k, rails at 31k). The reftable format provides:
>
> - **Near constant time lookup for any single reference**, even when the repository is cold and not in process or kernel cache.
> - **Near constant time verification if a SHA-1** is referred to by at least one reference (for allow-tip-sha1-in-want).
> - **Efficient lookup of an entire namespace**, such as `refs/tags/`. - Support atomic push `O(size_of_update)` operations. - Combine reflog storage with ref storage.
>
> This file format spec was originally written in July, 2017 by Shawn Pearce.
>
> Some refinements since then were made by Shawn and by Han-Wen Nienhuys based on experiences implementing and experimenting with the format.
>
> (All of this was in the context of our work at Google and Google is happy to contribute the result to the Git project.)
>
> Imported from [JGit](https://eclipse.googlesource.com/jgit/jgit)'s current version ([c217d33ff](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/commit/c217d33ff89bc39b084e4269cf0255a5d4a9ae93), "Documentation/technical/reftable: improve repo layout", 2020-02-04, JGit v5.7.0.202002241735-m3) of [`Documentation/technical/reftable.md`](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/c217d33ff89bc39b084e4269cf0255a5d4a9ae93/Documentation/technical/reftable.md).

And it is adapted to **[SHA2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60088126/6309)**:

> ### [`reftable`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ee9681d94960e075f310ce8276539aa3169fd152): define version 2 of the spec to accomodate SHA256
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Han-Wen Nienhuys</sup>

> Version appends a hash ID to the file header, making it slightly larger.
>
> This commit also changes "SHA-1" into "object ID" in many places.

---

With Git 2.35 (Q1 2022), the "reftable" backend for the refs API, without integrating into the refs subsystem, has been added.

See [commit d860c86](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d860c86ba545920342cbc507fc34af461ab99152), [commit e793168](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e7931683645f65e8e483bdc3dabbf94ddf799cd7), [commit e48d427](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e48d427268f965bf381a2f4fa445b5ade7913880), [commit acb5334](https://github.com/git/git/commit/acb533440fc0ed32e195987b9946e948a9706560), [commit 1ae2b8c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1ae2b8cda84c4c662d8f60898e034d9643f097b6), [commit 3b34f63](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3b34f636df9e6c32c2e9b819cd5ad907497c62b7), [commit ffc97f1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ffc97f1a9e154262ae23bf2d6ec6c1541fa3b15a), [commit 46bc0e7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/46bc0e731a70716485bc3c8bdaf7e6e6f88073a9), [commit 17df8db](https://github.com/git/git/commit/17df8dbeba18c8c36f14c58815a03091ba61f895), [commit f14bd71](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f14bd7193490d9a8d42306dcc750b73aa26defdc), [commit 35425d1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/35425d1034f2a98d438da21c68334056af7033ca), [commit e581fd7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e581fd72319adcf378c97e19262dd4f46c7fbe07), [commit a322920](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a322920d0bb8a930c17dd824990f7e5fd026bb3f), [commit e303bf2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e303bf22f9ac1a3bf0cb384ecd925570e014a3f3), [commit 1214aa8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1214aa841bc825c97541a68f397227cb2bfd3f3c), [commit ef8a6c6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ef8a6c62687984f2562463286e60ec1c66242b5c), [commit 8900447](https://github.com/git/git/commit/890044708dcc6144aac928f3592cb8fa64ac0580), [commit 27f7ed2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/27f7ed2a073c2b25f77ab9abf51e78bf7fa1a50a) (07 Oct 2021), and [commit 27f3796](https://github.com/git/git/commit/27f3796ac1f9b711fae506f63186034ed178690c) (30 Aug 2021) by [Han-Wen Nienhuys (`hanwen`)](https://github.com/hanwen).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a4bbd13](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a4bbd13be360d93f51a0cea6eef436db8622b592), 15 Dec 2021)</sup>

> ### [`reftable`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/35425d1034f2a98d438da21c68334056af7033ca): a generic binary tree implementation
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Han-Wen Nienhuys</sup>

> The reftable format includes support for an `(OID => ref)` map.
> This map can speed up visibility and reachability checks.
> In particular, various operations along the fetch/push path within Gerrit have been sped up by using this structure.

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26962349/6309 and https://github.com/git/git/commit/cbe73331812ed0ac3c3b680ab3aab4e6d22a98ad

Answer (score 1):

Git 2.45 (Q2 2024), [batch 1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a2082dbdd315aa4dd3f315545e5b3ab3b3e2d894), integrates the **reftable** code into the refs framework as a backend.

This is officially a new backend, which is another way how git branches and tags are stored in disks.

See [commit 8a0bebd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8a0bebdeaec60623c8a791b197d574bdd031a452) (08 Feb 2024), and [commit c0350cb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c0350cb96465b152ce67ef381af058594713f99b), [commit 57db2a0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/57db2a094d5ec781abc05d682c20d4eaa9dbdc11) (07 Feb 2024) by [Patrick Steinhardt (`pks-t`)](https://github.com/pks-t).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit b4385bf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b4385bf016d0d4b8e9bea6564e2d727082067f69), 26 Feb 2024)</sup>

> ### [`refs`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/57db2a094d5ec781abc05d682c20d4eaa9dbdc11): introduce reftable backend
>
> <sup>Original-idea-by: Shawn Pearce</sup>
> <sup>Based-on-patch-by: Han-Wen Nienhuys</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Patrick Steinhardt</sup>

> Due to scalability issues, Shawn Pearce has originally proposed a new "**`reftable`**" format [more than six years ago](https://public-inbox.org/git/CAJo=hJtyof=HRy=2sLP0ng0uZ4=S-DpZ5dR1aF+VHVETKG20OQ@mail.gmail.com/).
> Initially, this new format was implemented in JGit with promising results.
>
> Around two years ago, we have then added the "reftable" library to the Git codebase via [a4bbd13](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a4bbd13be360d93f51a0cea6eef436db8622b592) ("Merge branch 'hn/reftable'", 2021-12-15, Git v2.35.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a4bbd13be360d93f51a0cea6eef436db8622b592) listed in [batch #3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/69a9c10c95e28df457e33b3c7400b16caf2e2962)).
> With this we have landed all the low-level code to read and write reftables.
> Notably missing though was the integration of this low-level code into the Git code base in the form of a new ref backend that ties all of this together.
>
> That gap is now finally closed by introducing a new "reftable" backend into the Git codebase.
>
> That new backend promises to bring some notable improvements to Git repositories:
>
> - It becomes possible to do truly atomic writes where either all refs are committed to disk or none are.
>   That was not possible with the "files" backend because ref updates were split across multiple loose files.
> - The disk space required to store many refs is reduced, both compared to loose refs and packed-refs.
>   That is enabled both by the reftable format being a binary format, which is more compact, and by prefix compression.
> - We can ignore filesystem-specific behaviour as ref names are not encoded via paths anymore.
>   That means there is no need to handle case sensitivity on Windows systems or Unicode precomposition on macOS.
> - There is no need to rewrite the complete refdb anymore every time a ref is being deleted like it was the case for packed-refs.
>   That means that ref deletions are now constant time instead of scaling linearly with the number of refs.
> - We can ignore file/directory conflicts so that it becomes possible to store both "refs/heads/foo" and "refs/heads/foo/bar".
> - Due to this property we can retain reflogs for deleted refs.
>   We have previously been deleting reflogs together with their refs to avoid file/directory conflicts, which is not necessary anymore.
> - We can properly enumerate all refs.
>   With the "files" backend it is not easily possible to distinguish between refs and non-refs because they may live side by side in the gitdir.
>
> Not all of these improvements are realized with the current "`reftable`" backend implementation.
>
> **At this point, the new backend is supposed to be a drop-in replacement for the "`files`" backend that is used by basically all Git repositories nowadays.**
>
> It strives for 1:1 compatibility, which means that a user can expect the same behaviour regardless of whether they use the "`reftable`" backend or the "`files`" backend for most of the part.
>
> Most notably, this means we artificially limit the capabilities of the "`reftable`" backend to match the limits of the "`files`" backend.
> It is not possible to create refs that would end up with file/directory conflicts, we do not retain reflogs, we perform stricter-than-necessary checks.
> That is done intentionally due to two main reasons:
>
> - It makes it significantly easier to land the "`reftable`" backend as tests behave the same.
>   It would be tough to argue for each and every single test that does not pass with the "`reftable`" backend.
> - It ensures compatibility between repositories that use the "`files`" backend and repositories that use the "`reftable`" backend.
>   Like this, hosters can migrate their repositories to use the "`reftable`" backend without causing issues for clients that use the "`files`" backend in their clones.
>
> It is expected that these artificial limitations may eventually go away in the long term.
>
> Performance-wise things very much depend on the actual workload.
> The following benchmarks compare the "files" and "reftable" backends in the current version:
>
> - Creating N refs in separate transactions shows that the "files" backend is ~50% faster.
>   That is not surprising given that creating a ref only requires us to create a single loose ref.
>   The "reftable" backend will also perform auto compaction on updates.
>   In real-world workloads we would likely also want to perform pack loose refs, which would likely change the picture.
>
>   ```
>   Benchmark 1: update-ref: create refs sequentially (refformat = files, refcount = 1)
>     Time (mean ± σ):       2.1 ms ±   0.3 ms    [User: 0.6 ms, System: 1.7 ms]
>     Range (min … max):     1.8 ms …   4.3 ms    133 runs
>
>   Benchmark 2: update-ref: create refs sequentially (refformat = reftable, refcount = 1)
>     Time (mean ± σ):       2.7 ms ±   0.1 ms    [User: 0.6 ms, System: 2.2 ms]
>     Range (min … max):     2.4 ms …   2.9 ms    132 runs
>
>   Benchmark 3: update-ref: create refs sequentially (refformat = files, refcount = 1000)
>     Time (mean ± σ):      1.975 s ±  0.006 s    [User: 0.437 s, System: 1.535 s]
>     Range (min … max):    1.969 s …  1.980 s    3 runs
>
>   Benchmark 4: update-ref: create refs sequentially (refformat = reftable, refcount = 1000)
>     Time (mean ± σ):      2.611 s ±  0.013 s    [User: 0.782 s, System: 1.825 s]
>     Range (min … max):    2.597 s …  2.622 s    3 runs
>
>   Benchmark 5: update-ref: create refs sequentially (refformat = files, refcount = 100000)
>     Time (mean ± σ):     198.442 s ±  0.241 s    [User: 43.051 s, System: 155.250 s]
>     Range (min … max):   198.189 s … 198.670 s    3 runs
>
>   Benchmark 6: update-ref: create refs sequentially (refformat = reftable, refcount = 100000)
>     Time (mean ± σ):     294.509 s ±  4.269 s    [User: 104.046 s, System: 190.326 s]
>     Range (min … max):   290.223 s … 298.761 s    3 runs
>   ```
> - Creating N refs in a single transaction shows that the "files" backend is significantly slower once we start to write many refs.
>   The "reftable" backend only needs to update two files, whereas the "files" backend needs to write one file per ref.
>
>   ```
>   Benchmark 1: update-ref: create many refs (refformat = files, refcount = 1)
>     Time (mean ± σ):       1.9 ms ±   0.1 ms    [User: 0.4 ms, System: 1.4 ms]
>     Range (min … max):     1.8 ms …   2.6 ms    151 runs
>
>   Benchmark 2: update-ref: create many refs (refformat = reftable, refcount = 1)
>     Time (mean ± σ):       2.5 ms ±   0.1 ms    [User: 0.7 ms, System: 1.7 ms]
>     Range (min … max):     2.4 ms …   3.4 ms    148 runs
>
>   Benchmark 3: update-ref: create many refs (refformat = files, refcount = 1000)
>     Time (mean ± σ):     152.5 ms ±   5.2 ms    [User: 19.1 ms, System: 133.1 ms]
>     Range (min … max):   148.5 ms … 167.8 ms    15 runs
>
>   Benchmark 4: update-ref: create many refs (refformat = reftable, refcount = 1000)
>     Time (mean ± σ):      58.0 ms ±   2.5 ms    [User: 28.4 ms, System: 29.4 ms]
>     Range (min … max):    56.3 ms …  72.9 ms    40 runs
>
>   Benchmark 5: update-ref: create many refs (refformat = files, refcount = 1000000)
>     Time (mean ± σ):     152.752 s ±  0.710 s    [User: 20.315 s, System: 131.310 s]
>     Range (min … max):   152.165 s … 153.542 s    3 runs
>
>   Benchmark 6: update-ref: create many refs (refformat = reftable, refcount = 1000000)
>     Time (mean ± σ):     51.912 s ±  0.127 s    [User: 26.483 s, System: 25.424 s]
>     Range (min … max):   51.769 s … 52.012 s    3 runs
>   ```
> - Deleting a ref in a fully-packed repository shows that the "files" backend scales with the number of refs.
>   The "reftable" backend has constant-time deletions.
>
>   ```
>   Benchmark 1: update-ref: delete ref (refformat = files, refcount = 1)
>     Time (mean ± σ):       1.7 ms ±   0.1 ms    [User: 0.4 ms, System: 1.2 ms]
>     Range (min … max):     1.6 ms …   2.1 ms    316 runs
>
>   Benchmark 2: update-ref: delete ref (refformat = reftable, refcount = 1)
>     Time (mean ± σ):       1.8 ms ±   0.1 ms    [User: 0.4 ms, System: 1.3 ms]
>     Range (min … max):     1.7 ms …   2.1 ms    294 runs
>
>   Benchmark 3: update-ref: delete ref (refformat = files, refcount = 1000)
>     Time (mean ± σ):       2.0 ms ±   0.1 ms    [User: 0.5 ms, System: 1.4 ms]
>     Range (min … max):     1.9 ms …   2.5 ms    287 runs
>
>   Benchmark 4: update-ref: delete ref (refformat = reftable, refcount = 1000)
>     Time (mean ± σ):       1.9 ms ±   0.1 ms    [User: 0.5 ms, System: 1.3 ms]
>     Range (min … max):     1.8 ms …   2.1 ms    217 runs
>
>   Benchmark 5: update-ref: delete ref (refformat = files, refcount = 1000000)
>     Time (mean ± σ):     229.8 ms ±   7.9 ms    [User: 182.6 ms, System: 46.8 ms]
>     Range (min … max):   224.6 ms … 245.2 ms    6 runs
>
>   Benchmark 6: update-ref: delete ref (refformat = reftable, refcount = 1000000)
>     Time (mean ± σ):       2.0 ms ±   0.0 ms    [User: 0.6 ms, System: 1.3 ms]
>     Range (min … max):     2.0 ms …   2.1 ms    3 runs
>   ```
> - Listing all refs shows no significant advantage for either of the backends.
>   The "files" backend is a bit faster, but not by a significant margin.
>   When repositories are not packed the "reftable" backend outperforms the "files" backend because the "reftable" backend performs auto-compaction.
>
>   ```
>   Benchmark 1: show-ref: print all refs (refformat = files, refcount = 1, packed = true)
>     Time (mean ± σ):       1.6 ms ±   0.1 ms    [User: 0.4 ms, System: 1.1 ms]
>     Range (min … max):     1.5 ms …   2.0 ms    1729 runs
>
>   Benchmark 2: show-ref: print all refs (refformat = reftable, refcount = 1, packed = true)
>     Time (mean ± σ):       1.6 ms ±   0.1 ms    [User: 0.4 ms, System: 1.1 ms]
>     Range (min … max):     1.5 ms …   1.8 ms    1816 runs
>
>   Benchmark 3: show-ref: print all refs (refformat = files, refcount = 1000, packed = true)
>     Time (mean ± σ):       4.3 ms ±   0.1 ms    [User: 0.9 ms, System: 3.3 ms]
>     Range (min … max):     4.1 ms …   4.6 ms    645 runs
>
>   Benchmark 4: show-ref: print all refs (refformat = reftable, refcount = 1000, packed = true)
>     Time (mean ± σ):       4.5 ms ±   0.2 ms    [User: 1.0 ms, System: 3.3 ms]
>     Range (min … max):     4.2 ms …   5.9 ms    643 runs
>
>   Benchmark 5: show-ref: print all refs (refformat = files, refcount = 1000000, packed = true)
>     Time (mean ± σ):      2.537 s ±  0.034 s    [User: 0.488 s, System: 2.048 s]
>     Range (min … max):    2.511 s …  2.627 s    10 runs
>
>   Benchmark 6: show-ref: print all refs (refformat = reftable, refcount = 1000000, packed = true)
>     Time (mean ± σ):      2.712 s ±  0.017 s    [User: 0.653 s, System: 2.059 s]
>     Range (min … max):    2.692 s …  2.752 s    10 runs
>
>   Benchmark 7: show-ref: print all refs (refformat = files, refcount = 1, packed = false)
>     Time (mean ± σ):       1.6 ms ±   0.1 ms    [User: 0.4 ms, System: 1.1 ms]
>     Range (min … max):     1.5 ms …   1.9 ms    1834 runs
>
>   Benchmark 8: show-ref: print all refs (refformat = reftable, refcount = 1, packed = false)
>     Time (mean ± σ):       1.6 ms ±   0.1 ms    [User: 0.4 ms, System: 1.1 ms]
>     Range (min … max):     1.4 ms …   2.0 ms    1840 runs
>
>   Benchmark 9: show-ref: print all refs (refformat = files, refcount = 1000, packed = false)
>     Time (mean ± σ):      13.8 ms ±   0.2 ms    [User: 2.8 ms, System: 10.8 ms]
>     Range (min … max):    13.3 ms …  14.5 ms    208 runs
>
>   Benchmark 10: show-ref: print all refs (refformat = reftable, refcount = 1000, packed = false)
>     Time (mean ± σ):       4.5 ms ±   0.2 ms    [User: 1.2 ms, System: 3.3 ms]
>     Range (min … max):     4.3 ms …   6.2 ms    624 runs
>
>   Benchmark 11: show-ref: print all refs (refformat = files, refcount = 1000000, packed = false)
>     Time (mean ± σ):     12.127 s ±  0.129 s    [User: 2.675 s, System: 9.451 s]
>     Range (min … max):   11.965 s … 12.370 s    10 runs
>
>   Benchmark 12: show-ref: print all refs (refformat = reftable, refcount = 1000000, packed = false)
>     Time (mean ± σ):      2.799 s ±  0.022 s    [User: 0.735 s, System: 2.063 s]
>     Range (min … max):    2.769 s …  2.836 s    10 runs
>   ```
> - Printing a single ref shows no real difference between the "files" and "reftable" backends.
>
>   ```
>   Benchmark 1: show-ref: print single ref (refformat = files, refcount = 1)
>     Time (mean ± σ):       1.5 ms ±   0.1 ms    [User: 0.4 ms, System: 1.0 ms]
>     Range (min … max):     1.4 ms …   1.8 ms    1779 runs
>
>   Benchmark 2: show-ref: print single ref (refformat = reftable, refcount = 1)
>     Time (mean ± σ):       1.6 ms ±   0.1 ms    [User: 0.4 ms, System: 1.1 ms]
>     Range (min … max):     1.4 ms …   2.5 ms    1753 runs
>
>   Benchmark 3: show-ref: print single ref (refformat = files, refcount = 1000)
>     Time (mean ± σ):       1.5 ms ±   0.1 ms    [User: 0.3 ms, System: 1.1 ms]
>     Range (min … max):     1.4 ms …   1.9 ms    1840 runs
>
>   Benchmark 4: show-ref: print single ref (refformat = reftable, refcount = 1000)
>     Time (mean ± σ):       1.6 ms ±   0.1 ms    [User: 0.4 ms, System: 1.1 ms]
>     Range (min … max):     1.5 ms …   2.0 ms    1831 runs
>
>   Benchmark 5: show-ref: print single ref (refformat = files, refcount = 1000000)
>     Time (mean ± σ):       1.6 ms ±   0.1 ms    [User: 0.4 ms, System: 1.1 ms]
>     Range (min … max):     1.5 ms …   2.1 ms    1848 runs
>
>   Benchmark 6: show-ref: print single ref (refformat = reftable, refcount = 1000000)
>     Time (mean ± σ):       1.6 ms ±   0.1 ms    [User: 0.4 ms, System: 1.1 ms]
>     Range (min … max):     1.5 ms …   2.1 ms    1762 runs
>   ```
>
> So overall, performance depends on the usecases.
>
> Except for many sequential writes the "`reftable`" backend is roughly on par or significantly faster than the "`files`" backend though.
> Given that the "`files`" backend has received 18 years of optimizations by now this can be seen as a win.
> Furthermore, we can expect that the "`reftable`" backend will grow faster over time when attention turns more towards optimizations.
>
> The complete test suite passes, except for those tests explicitly marked to require the `REFFILES` prerequisite.
> Some tests in `t0610` are marked as failing because they depend on still-in-flight bug fixes.
> Tests can be run with the new backend by setting the `GIT_TEST_DEFAULT_REF_FORMAT` environment variable to "reftable".
>
> There is a single known conceptual incompatibility with the dumb HTTP transport.
> As "`info/refs`" SHOULD NOT contain the HEAD reference, and because the "`HEAD`" file is not valid anymore, it is impossible for the remote client to figure out the default branch without changing the protocol.
> That shortcoming needs to be handled in a subsequent patch series.
>
> Please refer to our preexisting technical documentation at [**`Documentation/technical/reftable`**](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b4385bf016d0d4b8e9bea6564e2d727082067f69/Documentation/technical/reftable.txt) for details of how exactly the on-disk format works.

`ref-storage-format` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/57db2a094d5ec781abc05d682c20d4eaa9dbdc11/Documentation/ref-storage-format.txt#L2-L3):

> - `reftable` for the reftable format.
>   That format is experimental and its internals are subject to change.

`technical/repository-version` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/57db2a094d5ec781abc05d682c20d4eaa9dbdc11/Documentation/technical/repository-version.txt#L106-L108):

> Specifies the file format for the ref database. The valid values are
> `files` (loose references with a packed-refs file) and `reftable` (see
> Documentation/technical/reftable.txt).

Comment: Optimizations are already in progress with [commit 9f67cbd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9f67cbd0a7725857d219da6720fc9a5acfda2960)