# Search git reflog

Tags: git

I create a new branch when a new issue pops up. These branches are named starting  `issu`. After merging with `master` these branches are deleted. I wanted to get a list of all such branches. I was able to get it using `git reflog`

```
>git reflog
55e8b45 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{0}: merge issu4-HasScript-and-HasFormat-checkbox-toggle: Fast-forward
7caf2c6 HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from issu4-HasScript-and-HasFormat-checkbox-toggle to master
55e8b45 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{2}: commit (amend): Column validation including Has-Script and Has-Format
490a29a HEAD@{3}: commit: Column validatio inclnsuding Has Script and Has Format
7caf2c6 HEAD@{4}: checkout: moving from master to issu4-HasScript-and-HasFormat-checkbox-toggle
7caf2c6 HEAD@{5}: merge issu3-make-SFTPFingerprint-required: Fast-forward
fbad7cd HEAD@{6}: checkout: moving from issu3-make-SFTPFingerprint-required to master
...
```

Is there any way to filter these entries to get all merges starting with `issu`.

I am trying to get all deleted branches that were merged into the master and started with `issu`. Other solutions that get these are also fine.

I searched a lot and could not find a solution.

**Update:**

I am using windows. The solution that i currently have is

```
git reflog | findstr /c:"merge issu"
```

Is there any solution in git itself?

Comment: have you tried using git reflog | grep issu?

Comment: @DaveG I am on a windows machine.

Comment: see answer from Saurabh.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use this command,

`git reflog --grep-reflog=<pattern>`

In your case it would be, `git reflog --grep-reflog="merge issu"`

[Link](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---grep-reflogltpatterngt)

Comment: Interesting note here from the git reflog documentation: `The "show" subcommand (which is also the default, in the absence of any subcommands) shows the log of the reference provided in the command-line (or HEAD, by default). The reflog covers all recent actions, and in addition the HEAD reflog records branch switching. git reflog show is an alias for git log -g --abbrev-commit --pretty=oneline; see git-log[1] for more information.` Meaning, any options that go to `git log` can be used - it is not immediately evident from the help page for reflog that this is an option

Answer (score 1):

With Git 2.45 (Q2 2024), [batch 3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b387623c12f3f4a376e4d35a610fd3e55d7ea907), "[`git reflog`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/510a27e9e48ae13ebf94a71041878445aba29f8c/Documentation/git-reflog.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog))</sup> learned a list subcommand that enumerates known reflogs.

That could help in your case, to list all branches with reflog entries.

See [commit f7cdeaf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f7cdeafdd018ba143e0b2d7ef826b65ead923eac) (19 Feb 2024) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
See [commit d699d15](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d699d15c328b03fd822d3950f7ed76debef02c26), [commit 59c50a9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/59c50a96c5d2e58f981e0ceceaeadd941d5a19b7), [commit 31f8983](https://github.com/git/git/commit/31f898397bb2f44692b8bcc4fd64fffaf3b59c48), [commit 5e01d83](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5e01d838412d6679c40c929bbb2591669ae393d4), [commit 6f22780](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6f227800176d7ed1d1c50d64ef5d5e485f5fbee3), [commit e69e8ff](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e69e8ffef7369ca0d24c570d2657e41cf5e45936), [commit de34f26](https://github.com/git/git/commit/de34f2651ecca00dffeb61934253345150a1cc32), [commit 0218de2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0218de2bdbd13975c31c3944775d0d7a6cd73e7b) (21 Feb 2024) by [Patrick Steinhardt (`pks-t`)](https://github.com/pks-t).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 510a27e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/510a27e9e48ae13ebf94a71041878445aba29f8c), 01 Mar 2024)</sup>

> ### [`builtin/reflog`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d699d15c328b03fd822d3950f7ed76debef02c26): introduce subcommand to list reflogs
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Patrick Steinhardt</sup>

> While the `git-reflog`(1) command has subcommands to show reflog entries or check for reflog existence, it does not have any subcommands that would allow the user to enumerate all existing reflogs.
> This makes it quite hard to discover which reflogs a repository has.
> While this can be worked around with the "files" backend by enumerating files in the "`.git/logs`" directory, users of the ["`reftable`" backend](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78096659/6309) don't enjoy such a luxury.
>
> Introduce a new subcommand [`git reflog`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d699d15c328b03fd822d3950f7ed76debef02c26/Documentation/git-reflog.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog))</sup> list that lists all reflogs the repository knows of to fill this gap.

`git reflog` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d699d15c328b03fd822d3950f7ed76debef02c26/Documentation/git-reflog.txt#L13):

> ### '`git reflog list`'

`git reflog` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d699d15c328b03fd822d3950f7ed76debef02c26/Documentation/git-reflog.txt#L43-L44):

> The "list" subcommand lists all refs which have a corresponding reflog.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux, `grep` is the tool for this job, along with pipes which allow you to take the output from one command as the input for another command. In this case, you can do

```
git reflog | grep issu
```

For more info, type `man grep` for the grep documentation.

Note: In all Windows flavors, you can use Git Bash to do this. In Windows 10, you can use the Linux subsystem.

Comment: I am using windows

Comment: @PyMan already tried [`findstr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/findstr)?