# git/github: Remove from history (but not from HEAD) some large binary files

Tags: git, github

I am using git / github for a project. It is mostly to host code sources, but it also contains some large images.
I will have to update the large images from time to time, but I don't want to keep the history of it, I only want the latest version in my git / github.

Is there a way to say to git: "keep this file, but don't keep any history of it"?
If not, how can I manually and safely delete the history of my file right after commit / push?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: This is not exactly what you want but still might be helpful: https://git-annex.branchable.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I see two possible solutions.

#### First solution ("dirty")

Develop using one branch that always has one last commit that adds **large files**.
All commits except this one should NOT add any of that **large files**.
To make changes to **source** files you'll need to commit on top of that **large** one, and then use `git rebase` (example that assumes that you are working in **master** branch: `git checkout -b src HEAD~1 && git cherry-pick master && git rebase src master && git branch -d src`) command to pop **large** commit on top of all **source** commits.
To update the set of **large files** you'll need to make that **large** commit to be the last one and amend it instead of creating new one.
In this case you'll be unable to use default `git push` behavior that makes only fast-forward refs updates and you'll have to make forced updates like `git push <repository> +master:master` (note the **+** sign).

#### Second solution ("clean")

UPD: There is similar question with similar answer [Managing large binary files with git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540535/managing-large-binary-files-with-git).
I noticed that after I wrote my answer.

Create separate repository for **large files** and use it in main repository as [git submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).
To make modifications to **source** files you can simply make regular commit in main repo.
And when you'll need to update the set of **large files** in submodule repo you'll have to amend the only commit there instead of making new one.