# How can I git push mp4 ogg webm files?

Tags: git, github, git-push

I have mp4, ogg, and webm files in my project, and when I try to push it, it tells me that the files are too large to be pushed.

What would be the best approach to pushing these files along with my project at once?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Managing large binary files with git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540535/managing-large-binary-files-with-git)

Comment: You might want to avoid pushing large binary files to GitHub, as Git does not handle binaries very well.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen is there a way to have them compressed in my project, yet still be able to use them in the code, e.g with src=""?

Comment: You can certainly version compressed MP4 files (or any file), but I think you would need to uncompress them to use them.

Comment: @JohnBana "is there a way to have them compressed?" Compressing video files usually doesn't (significantly) reduce their size, since all video formats are internally compressed.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at git [Large File Storage](https://git-lfs.github.com/). GitHub already supports it.

Comment: is there a way to have them compressed in my project, yet still be able to use them in the code, e.g with src=""?

Comment: @JohnBana : You can create a `.tar` file and pushed it to git. And ignore it's extracted form. Though it's a very bad idea.