# How to have a file in git but not it's history?

Tags: git

I don't actually need the history of one particular file in my repository, I just need the latest version in git. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What is the concern? Git is **version** control software. It tracks versions.

Comment: There is no such thing as file history. There are only commits, and the commits *are* the history. The file is either in some commits, or it's not in the repository. (Or, in other words: no.)

Comment: Your main alternative here is to store the file somewhere outside Git. Then it's not in Git, and therefore not version-controlled by Git, and has no history. But it's not in the repository.

Comment: @DanielMann my main problem is that when the file is quite big (example a mp4) it's make the size of the repository very big every time you change this file and that forever, even if you delete this file it's still in the history :( Option to store it somewhere else is not possible

Comment: There are a few options for managing large binary files with Git that may work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540535/managing-large-binary-files-with-git

Comment: @torek But how to avoid a repository to grow like hell when you have some big files in it? if it's grow on the server side it's not a problem for me, the problem is that the repository grow on my local hard drive :(

Comment: Don't put such files into Git. See @Basil's link.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can tag just the one file. That's so very far from a standard workflow that none of Git's convenience commands will know what to do with it, but the Git core is about building the exact work flow you need.

```
git tag particular.file `git hash-object -w that/particular.file`
git push origin particular.file
```

Then on origin or any place that has fetched the `particular.file` tag,

```
git show particular.file
```

You might need to force some updates when changing versions, and you might want to make it an annotated tag since those at least carry timestamps.

Comment: but is that user that simply do a git -clone url will immediatly see this file or they will be force to do a git show particular.file ?

Comment: You specifically said you "just need the latest version in git". Let me know when you've got the goalposts where you really want them.